# RequireJS + oCanvas with self-invoking functions

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I have troubles with using oCanvas - it doesn't support AMD out of box so in RequireJS I define a shim:
**configuration.js**

```
require(
    function () {
        requirejs.config({
            shim: {
                'lib/ocanvas': {
                    exports: ['oCanvas']
                }
            }
        });
    }
);
```

The way I load shim-related configuration (I think it's enough to add it to `require` to the entry point file):

```
require(['configuration','main'],
    function (configuration, main) {
        main.startUniverse();
    }
);
```

The problem is I cannot get the `oCanvas` object in my JS files:

```
define(['lib/ocanvas'],
    function (oCanvas) {}
```

It appears undefined here. In [oCanvas sources](http://ocanvas.org/source/ocanvas-2.5.1.js) I see that there are 2 self-invoking functions and they put the `oCanvas` object into global state like that: `window.oCanvas = oCanvas`. Maybe this doesn't work for RequireJS?

Comment: I thought you pass the global var that is being used in a non AMD compliant script as a string to exports, not an array (like in deps)

Comment: I've seen samples with arrays. Moreover returning a string doesn't change the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `requirejs.config` I now use `require.config` and pass an object there:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        'lib/ocanvas': {
            exports: 'oCanvas'
        }
    }
});
```

That worked for me.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: I'm sorry, between require.config() and requirejs.config()?

Answer (score 1):

```
require(
    function () {
        requirejs.config({
            shim: {
                'lib/ocanvas': {
                    exports: 'oCanvas'
                }
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Try passing it as a string not an array?

Comment: Sadly that doesn't help. I actually have seen somewhere samples with arrays.

Comment: It's hard to imagine those would be *working* examples; the documentation explicitly states that the value for the `exports` property is a string (how would one interpret multiple exports, anyway? aliases?)